# Include Shipment and Inoices pdf generator in order grid in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf, order-grid, shipment

As in magento 1, there is Shipment and invoice Pdf generator in order grid also.
[image]
How can i include that in magento 2 as well.
I want to include and shipment and invoce pdf generator in order grid Action tab as well.
https://prnt.sc/t42n33

Answer (score 1):

There is NO any "Print Shipment and Invoices" option in Vanilla Magento 1.x. It seems you might have any third party extension or customized code for it. So the solution would be

i) To get the M2 version of the extension you are using for your M1 site
ii) Or Migrate the customized code in M2

Add-On:
Rather there is a "Print All" option available in M1 & M2 which prints invoices & Packing slips unless you do not have a customized print layout, see if it helps you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link To add Custom mass action in order grid : https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-custom-mass-action-in-order-grid-in-magento-2/